# Convert datestring to date() in qml

Tags: string, qt, date, qml, date-conversion

i need to convert date string "28/01/2018" (dd/mm/yyyy) into a Date() in qml.

i'm tried this:

```
  var dateBoard = masterPAGEMAIN.getData();

  var locale = Qt.locale()

  var someDateTest = new Date()
  someDateTest = Date.fromLocaleString(locale, dateBoard, "dd/MM/yyyy");
  var test = someDateTest.getDate().toString();
```

Also saw this: 
[conversione from string](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-date.html#fromLocaleString-method)
, but my problem is that i continue to receive a "NaN" or "Invalid Date", how to can i get Date() from string in qml ?

Thanks

Comment: the syntax looks javascript with qml?

Comment: @MohammadKanan yes it's like javascript

Comment: Please read [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-date.html#details) Qt documentation page carefully. There is no 'gg' expression. Probably you want 'dd' instead.

Comment: i'm wrong wrote but the problem it's not resolved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string passed to `fromLocaleString` must be in the expected format. Try this code:

```
var dateBoard = "01/31/2018"
var someDateTest = Date.fromLocaleString(Qt.locale(), dateBoard, "dd/MM/yyyy")
var test = someDateTest.getDate() //nan
```

Since the string in `dateBoard` represents a date in *MM/dd/yyyy* format, `fromLocaleString` will return an invalid date and `getDate` `nan`, accordingly.

Same applies if `dateBoard` is an empty string, null or undefined.